# Disable the /blog route

Tags: routes

I'm using Drupal 6.16. I would like to permanently disable the /blog path (and all its sub-paths, but not the Blog module.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with `hook_menu_alter()` in a custom module or theme, for example using the following code.

```
function custom_module_menu_alter(&$items) {
  unset($items['blog']);
  unset($items['blog/%user_uid_optional']);
  unset($items['blog/%user/feed']);
  unset($items['blog/feed']);
  return $items;
}
```

Make sure to clear the cache.

Answer (score 2):

The path redirect module will allow you to send users from 1 URL to another.  https://drupal.org/project/path_redirect

In your case:
- Download and install this module
- Visit the modules admin page
- Add a redirect from 'blog' to 'node/1' (as an example)

People attempting to go to '/blog' would then be redirected to your entered location

Not sure you can wildcard the URL, but you can add certain URLs as above.  To stop content being created under 'blog/blog-a' you could setup an auto path alias for created blogs.
- visit /admin/build/path/pathauto
- Create an auto path for node of type blogs

Blogs will then be created with your chosen alias.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

REDIRECT ACCORDING TO THE GEOLOCATON

```
  function geo_redirect_init() {
  $geoPlugin_array = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );

   if ($geoPlugin_array['geoplugin_countryCode'] != "GB" && (!isset($_SESSION['non_uk_redirect']) || $_SESSION['non_uk_redirect'] === false)) {
     $_SESSION['non_uk_redirect'] = true;
     drupal_goto("/blog");
   }
  }
```